# How reliable is the metric of active users in predicting market trends in the DeFi space, given that it is relatively easy to create a wallet?

Tags: decentralization

Gm from the Equator. Hope your all well!

In the Defi space all the prediction data is based on active users I disagree with this form of measure for predicting what the market will do because of how easy it is make a wallet. I'm now curious is it possible for a project( be it NFTs or ERC-20 tokens) to ddos its own network not to break it but boost the active user numbers. If so I suspect a lot of these Defi projects are rug pulls waiting to happen.

To conclude I do not think the number of active users on using the network- keep in mind 'using the network' CANNOT be the same as 'on the network'( I just might outline what's my 5sat on the matter). As I was saying active users using the network is not a reliable metric to answer some of our questions like: does this project have any use case? does it have a strong team behind it? is it community centric or driven by (what I'm afraid is the case) greed!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it possible to artificially raise the number of users using say a defi application?